# Use default blue background when UITableViewCell is selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

For a better user experience, I would like my `UITableViewCell` to have the default blue styling when a user taps it. Currently, there is no styling at all. Shouldn't the following this be all I need?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
        animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    // [The rest of my code here that loads up the detail view]
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // [bunch of code]
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
        initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
        reuseIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier] autorelease];
    // [bunch of code that sets the text of the cell];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to *cellForRowAtIndexPath*  and use

```
cell.selectionStyle= UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
```

Comment: This solved the problem. I don't know why. According to the [UITableViewCell documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html), `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue` is already the default style. Plus, I've seen other sample code not redefine this default style, yet properly show the style when the cell is tapped.